# No viabale alternative input

Tags: python, input

I am brand new to python, and I am just experimenting with programs that I have already written in Java and C++.

The error I am getting is "No viable alternative input". I have found explanations for other languages on what this is, but not Python (the other ones didn't help me), and I was wandering what that means exactly, and how can I fix it?

I left a comment where the error is thrown.
My code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    yesNo = false
    print "Find out if x is divisible by y"
    x = (input("Enter x> "))
    y = (input("Enter y> "))

    if x % y == 0:
        print "Yes! ", x," is divisible by ", y,"."
        yesNo = true
    else:
        print "No! ", x," is not divisible by ", y, "."
    int randX, randY, result, answer, numberCorrect #the error is throw right here
    randX = randY = result = answer = numberCorrect = 0   
    print "Since it is divisible you will be asked addition questions till you get one wrong!"
    while yesNo:
         print "You have gotten ", numberCorrect, " correct."
         randX = (randInt(0,25))
         randY = (randInt(0,25))
         result = randX + randY
         answer = (input("What is ", randX, " + ", randY, "?> "))
         if answer != result:
            yesNo = false
         else:
            numberCorrect += 1
```

Comment: no need to declare variables in python, just delete that line which has no meaning in python langage. (Note that they will be `int` since you assign `0` which is of type `int` to your variables.)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it after I fixed a few syntax errors!

Comment: comment in python is with `#` instead of `//`

Comment: Thank you @Copperfield, thanks for the info, will be sure to use # instead

Comment: also `true` and `false` are, well, `True` and `False`, notice the capital T and F